# How do you execute functions on elements obtained with getElementById?

Tags: jquery, getelementbyid

Using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) you might execute a method against an element like this:

```
$('#myElement').show();
```

If the following is tried it raises a `TypeError: undefined is not a function` error:

```
document.getElementById('myElement').show();
```

The show() function is defined as:

```
MyClass.prototype.show = function () { }
```

How do you call the show() function without using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('myElement')` returns an object of type Element. If you want to add a function `show` to it you can do the following **NOTE: THIS IS NOT RECOMMENDED**:

```
Element.prototype.show = function() { return 'I am called!' }
document.getElementById('myElement').show(); // 'I am called!'
```

You should avoid adding custom methods to DOM elements at all cost. There is rarely, if ever, a good reason to do this.

Here is more info on why **NOT** to do this: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

If you are looking to replicate the functionality of jquery's `show` function you could do the following:

```
var _$ = function(selector) {

    var elem = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    var hasResults = elem.length > 0;

    var _show = function() {
        if (hasResults) {
            for (var i=0,l=elem.length;i<l;i++) {
                elem[i].style.display = "block";
            }
        }

        return this;
    }

    return {
       show : _show
    }

}

_$('#foo').show();
```

Or, using `document.getElementById`:

```
document.getElementById('myElement').style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Except that it is NOT recommended to add custom methods to DOM elements.